# flowtype how to annotate union with optional fields

Tags: flowtype

How to achieve the following in flow

```
export type Response = {
  err: string,
  data: ?Array<Object>,
} | {
  data: Array<Object>,
};
```

I want to express a type, which returns an error and optional data or no error field in case there none. But, which I use it as

```
return { err: 'todo' };
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
.... Response
union: object type(s)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Flow, there is a difference between optional fields and nullable values.

1. `{key: ?valueType}` means the object **must** contain `key`, and its value must be either `null` **or** of type `valueType`.
2. `{key?: valueType}` means the object **might** contain `key`, and if `key` is present, its value must be of type `valueType`.
3. `{key?: ?valueType}` means the object **might** contain `key`, and if `key` is present, its value must be either `null` **or** of type `valueType`.

Your use case needs either #2 or #3. Personally I would recommend not using #3 – I find that pattern more flexible than it needs to be.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. very subtle, and I would not have noticed. thanks again.

Comment: You just saved me from jumping out the window, thank you.

Comment: Where is the documentation for the `{key: ?valueType}`? It is not in https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/.

Comment: @Gajus `?valueType` is not specific to objects, as far as object syntax is concerned it's just *some* type. These docs here explain that prepending `?` to a type defines a "Maybe type": https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, my syntax was wrong for optional fields

```
export type Response = {
  err: string,
  data?: Array<Object>,
} | {
  data: Array<Object>,
};
```

this doesn't give any error. I don't know why there wasn't any syntax error reported for this.