# Flow type for optional field in an object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following code ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUEATsQFxQD88wxAligOYDc+hAJgIbCcUDyAIwBWEAMbBWAX1wAzAK4pxdVFAA2EJsAAWACgAeASgpxEqdDjbEIwOcRQ4oXHlArZJUSVNy51m3QEYABgMgA)):

```
type Response = {
    err: ?string;
    data: Object;
}
function length(x): Response {
  return { data : {} };
}

length(10)
```

I made `err` optional, but still get an error:

> Property `err` not found in object literal

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for an optional property:

```
type Response = {
    err?: string;
    data: Object;
}
```

[Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7e0C8UDeAoKBUEATsQPwBcU8wxAligOYDc+hAJgIbCdUDyAIwBWEAMbBWAX1y4AZgFcU4uqiiykSABTEqcRKnQBKPNNwA3TsShWs2LjyrZJk1nI3bDzIA)

The syntax you tried to use (`err: ?string`) is a [Maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/), 
which means the `err` key should be in the object and can have type `string`, `null`, or `void` (`undefined`).

Comment: thanks a ton. I can't believe I have been using it wrongly the whole time and never got any syntax warning!!

Comment: Explanation of optional fields vs nullable values in Flow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37174244/2601788